# Access Report - anchor fields

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a report that is laid out as two columns.  The column on the left has a number of fields, stacked.  These fields will not need to grow in height (maybe in width)  The second column has three fields, stacked on top of each other. These will grow in height.  The problem is that when they grow, they also push down the fields in the left column.  I would like to keep all the fields on the left anchored in place, even if the ones on the right grow in height.

Also, when I say I have them arranged in columns, I just have them in close proximity.  Not grouped using any sub reports or anything.

Is there a way to do this?

thanks
jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to put one group (left or right) into a subreport, so that the other group can grow independently.

I would probably put the static fields (left) into the subreport, so that the others can grow beyond the page break, if necessary.

If you already have a query that returns the one record to print, you can base both reports on it. Otherwise, if the report shows multiple records, use the master/child linking between main and subreport.